# Edit Distance program

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that calculates the edit distance between any two words in the English language.  The edit distance is defined as the minimum number of steps it takes to go from one word to another by changing just one letter at a time, where each intermediate word is contained in some standard list of English words.  I will prompt the user for two words.  So for example, if the user enters: "trail" and "crawl" I want the output to be:

```
First word:  trail
Last word: crawl
The edit distance is 2 with the following chain: trail -> trawl -> crawl
```

(so it also includes the path as well)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class EditDistance {
 public static void main (String[] args) {
    try {
        inputDictionary();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: FileNotFoundException");
    }
    promptUser();
}

static ArrayList<String> dictionary;

    //input dictionary
public static void inputDictionary() throws FileNotFoundException {
    dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File ("dict.txt"));
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String word = scan.next();
        dictionary.add(word);
    }
    scan.close();
}

public static HashSet<String> changeOneLetter(String Word) {
    HashSet<String> newWords = new HashSet<String>();
    char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
        //take each letter and change it to a different letter
        for (int i = 0; i < Word.length(); i++) { //cycles through each letter of the word
            char wordArray[] = Word.toCharArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) { //swaps in each letter of the alphabet
                wordArray[i] = alphabet[j];
                //check if it's not the same as previous word
                String newWord = new String(wordArray);
                if (!newWord.equals(Word)) {
                    // if it's in the dictionary add the word to the set
                    for (String word1: dictionary) {
                        if (newWord.equals(word1)) {
                            newWords.add(newWord);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return newWords;
}

static Map<String, Set<String>> eachWordChange;
static String firstWord;
static String secondWord;

    //prompts the user for two words
public static void promptUser() {
    System.out.println("Enter the first word: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    firstWord = scan.next();
    for (String word1: dictionary) {
        if (firstWord.equals(word1)) {
            System.out.println("Enter the second word: ");
            secondWord = scan.next();
            for (String word2: dictionary) {
                if (secondWord.equals(word2)) {
                    calculateEdits();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    scan.close();
}

   //this is where I'm having trouble
public static void calculateEdits() {
    String oldWord = secondWord;
    Map <String, String> findPath = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashSet<String> oneLevel = changeOneLetter(oldWord);
    System.out.println("This is the first level: " + oneLevel);
    for (String word: oneLevel) {
        if (!firstWord.equals(word)) {

            findPath.put(word, secondWord);
            System.out.println("Next Levels: " + changeOneLetter(word));
    }
    System.out.println("Path of first level: " + findPath);
}
```

}

Right now I just have println's to show me what's going on, so right now it is showing me:

```
This is the first level: [trawl, brawl, drawl]
Next Levels: [brawl, trail, crawl, drawl]
Next Levels: [trawl, crawl, drawl]
Next Levels: [trawl, brawl, crawl, drawn]
Path of first level: {trawl=crawl, brawl=crawl, drawl=crawl}
```

Right now I have the first level, and can generate the second level from each of the first levels, but I want to be able to store those next levels, and then check if the first word (=trail) occurs there, and if it doesn't I'll have to create a map and redo the process until the first word appears.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I would suggest you use a `Set` as your dictionary as `contains` is `O(1)` - your current code uses a `List` on which `contains` is `O(n)`.

Comment: You know that there are known algorithms to solve this problem, such as Levenshtein and Ratcliff-Obershelp, right? I assume you're doing this as an assignment or for fun.